# Second Email verification in Parse.com opern source

Tags: parse-platform

I'm familiar how to verify the first user's email in Parse.

How do I verify second email address? Or any other email address (not just the login email address of a user).

Comment: Have you succeed with this? I have same problem. Can you help?

Comment: no success yet, I had to build my own verification system using Mailgun and parse server code